# Nodejs: trying to link an external lib: ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: node.js

I have a working nodejs projectA written in typescript. I generate a distribution with webpack, main entry point is dist/index.js.
I link with

```
npm link
```

Now, in projectB, I link the projects:

```
npm link projectA
```

In projectB source code, I can import classes from projects:

```
 import {someClass} from 'projectA'
```

VisualStudio seems to recognize it.
I compile it and I run the server on projectB.

But it crashes with

```
 ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

The culprit is projectA/dist/index.js

What am I doing wrong?

PS. I'm using last node/typescript versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests that the library you are using is made for browsers (where `window` exists) and node Node.js (where it doesn't).

Comment: yes, that's the obvious suspect, but I run the lib from server-side and it's working, so what should I do?

Comment: @Glasnhost i missed something in your question the first read. Why use webpack? It makes no sense server-side.

Comment: exactly, I just compiled with tsc and now it seems to work fine...I didn't know either why the project was compiled through webpack...thx!